# Git. Работа с заначкой (Stash)

Tags: git

Добрый день!

Я сделал часть работы в ветке(условно `old_branch`). Далее мне понадобилось перенести эту работу в другую ветку(условно `new_branch`). Так как работа не закончена, я не стал комитить изменения, а воспользовался заначкой(`stash`)

```
$ git stash
$ git stash branch new_branch
```

У меня создалась новая ветка `new_branch`, в которую перенеслись мои незакомиченные изменения. Все ОК.

Далее я вернулся на старую ветку и восстановил ее состояние до моих изменений

```
$ git checkout old_branch
$ git checkout -- .
```

Изменения откатились не только в старой ветке, но и в новой тоже (WTF?).
Понимаю что незакомиченные изменения потеряны навсегда, но есть ли способ восстановить заначку из новой ветки?

Comment: Великолепный перевод "stash". ))

Comment: @NickVolynkin Да, теперь мне тоже кажется забавным. Пол часа назад во всем интернете не нашлось бы стикера, чтоб изобразить мою бесконечную печаль!

Comment: Предлагаю грустный смайл со знаком бесконечности вместо глаз. Как-то так: `8-(`

Comment: Ребята, спас `Local History` в идее. Есть не только для файлов, но и для папок(Восстановил удаленные файлы). Ave ребятам из `JetBrains`, Ave!

Comment: Рад за вас. По сути вопроса: вы же понимаете, что при переключении веток несохраненные изменения в рабочей области остаются (а если есть конфликты, то вы просто ветки не переключите)?

Comment: @NickVolynkin Теперь понимаю. Не понимал до того как задал вопрос

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> У меня создалась новая ветка new_branch, в которую перенеслись мои незакомиченные изменения.

нет, они не «перенеслись». просто была создана новая ветка, копия той, в которой была создана «заначка» (stash), т.е., создан новый указатель на тот же самый коммит, который был текущим во время создания «заначки», затем эта новая ветка была назначена текущей, **к рабочему каталогу (working directory) были применены сохранённые в «заначке» изменения**, а сама «заначка» была удалена.

раз вы сразу после этого выполнили команду `checkout` (с аргументом `.`), то **изменения в рабочем каталоге были удалены**.

---

восстановить удалённую «заначку» теоретически можно (до проведения «сборки мусора»). пример:

```
$ git fsck --no-reflog
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
dangling commit 424c2946da3bfe5cbc719f808c1a006612e5cab7
```

найденный «подвисший» (dangling) коммит и является удалённой (мною) «заначкой». с этим хэшем можно манипулировать как с «обычной заначкой»:

```
$ git show 424c294
commit 424c2946da3bfe5cbc719f808c1a006612e5cab7
Merge: 3330f58 8a98560
Author: aleksandr barakin <a.barakin@...>
Date:   Fri Oct 6 12:46:55 2017 +0300

    WIP on master: 3330f58 20171006124552

diff --cc file
index abf3108,abf3108..e1743f8
--- a/file
+++ b/file
@@@ -1,1 -1,1 +1,2 @@@
  2017-10-06 12:45
++2017-10-06 12:46

$ git stash show -p 424c294
diff --git a/file b/file
index abf3108..e1743f8 100644
--- a/file
+++ b/file
@@ -1 +1,2 @@
 2017-10-06 12:45
+2017-10-06 12:46

$ git stash apply 424c29
On branch new
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   file

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Comment: Спасибо что разжевали. В целом меня уже спасла сама `IDEA`, даже дала восстановить удаленные файлы. Однако я все равно не понял, почему команда `$ git checkout -- .` на старой ветке затронула что-то на новой ветке. Или `$ git checkout -- .` работает безотносительно к веткам?

Comment: да, изменения в working directory (рабочем каталоге, рабочей копии), как и сама working directory, не имеют никакого отношения к репозиторию вообще и к веткам в частности. т.е., «существуют безотносительно к». репозиторий (с ветками, метками, коммитами, деревьями и прочими сущностями) — отдельно (обычно в каталоге `.git`), рабочая копия (со всеми изменениями) — отдельно.

Comment: Мне стало совершенно понятно почему так случилось. Век живи - век учись. Спасибо!