# Откат git stash pop

Tags: git

Я сделал `git stash pop`, восстановил изменения и удалил их из стека получается и тут... У меня крэшнулась студия :-(

В итоге изменений в стеке `stash` нет, студия их тоже не сохранила. Можно ли восстановить эти изменения?

Comment: @AK, там ответ на вопрос, можно ли отменить изменения, который вносит stash pop.

Comment: Если вы извлекли из стека, то восстановить стек не получится. Чтобы в  будущем не было таких конфузов, используйте git stash apply .

Comment: @aleshka-batman Точно, а я-то ещё думал, почему там reset на HEAD без собаки... Удаляю свой комментарий, чтобы не путать людей.

Comment: Пардон, оказывается можно откатит дропнутый стэш.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89332/how-to-recover-a-dropped-stash-in-git

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/727439/178576